# SharePoint 2013 Branding HTML 5 Master Page "s4-titlerowhidetitle" Not working to hide content

Tags: 2013, custom-masterpage

I've started with an HTML5 Master Page and am having trouble making the Header disappear when I use the ribbon functionality. The ribbon just pushes the Title down.  I would very much not like to add addition script to make this work. I have tried placing the class 
"s4-titlerowhidetitle"  in various tags to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Per Heather Solomon: Instead of class="titlerowhidtitle", an id="s4-titlerow" can be placed in the header. This causes it to be hidden when the ribbon is activated.